# SSL certificates in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I want to use SSl certificates in codename one.Currently I am using below code for connecting to server

```
ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest();
req.setUrl("http:/something");
```

But I want to use **https** instead of **http**.I want to import customize SSL certificates and want to use it in my app.

How to import and use SSL certificates ?

Answer (score 1):

You should just change this to HTTPS but you can't use a custom (invalid) SSL certificate. Your certificate must be valid and must be from a valid certificate authority for it to work.

If this is just for debugging you can add your debugging certificate to the device in the device settings which usually allows you to customize the root certificates.

Comment: I want to release my application thats why i want to make It https with valid SSL certificate.I have valid SSL certificates.I want to add this certificates in my app which is developed in codename one.How to add SSL certificates in codename one?

Comment: If it's a valid SSL certificate from a signing authority you don't need to do anything it will "just work". I'm assuming you have a failure so I suggest actually explaining how you generated the certificate and what's the error you are getting.