# SSL certificates in Codename One using Simulator

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, codenameone

I created a custom SSL certificate through Java keytool command, in order to test the connection from my Codename one app and my HTTPS REST web service.

This is the complete command:

`keytool -genkey -alias my_alias -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650`

When the app (running on the **simulator**) tries to interact with the web service, it returns the following exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795869/ssl-certificates-in-codename-one) 
and I understood for a real mobile device is possible to add the custom certificate.
My question is: using the simulator, how can I do? How can I use my "home-made" certificate?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, by "I created a custom SSL certificate through Java keytool".  What kind of certificate was it?

Comment: Keytool generated a self-signed **RSA** certificate inside a PKCS12 keystore. This is the command: `keytool -genkey -alias my_alias -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no reason to do this anymore. You can but if you just don't want to pay for a certificate you can just use "lets encrypt" and it will work: http://letsencrypt.org/

Notice that it requires a recent version of JDK 8 (I think 128 or newer).

SSL will only work with proper domains and not with IP addresses etc.

Comment: I'll try with a valid certificate from a certificate authority. Thanks for the explanation.